# Is this some kind of "omission" comma?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I think there's a comma that's used when you are omitting the subject and verb (perhaps to avoid a run-on sentence, which would be ungrammatical).

Examples:

> He felt good, like he was the king of the world.
>
> (He felt good, he felt like he was the kind of the world.)
>
> He said earnestly, with not the slightest hint of a smile.
>
> (He said earnestly, he said with not the slightest hint of a smile.)

I have two questions:

1. Is this the case? If not, what kind of comma is this?
2. Are these sentences grammatically correct without the commas?

Comment: We should note that a sentence like "He felt good, he felt like he was the king of the world" is technically a grammatical mistake called a [comma splice](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/the-comma-splice) because it is combining two complete sentences with just a comma between them.  We sometimes write this way in informal writing, but it's technically considered an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commas in question are not omitting anything, because there is no *he said* or *he felt* necessary.

In the first sentence, *like* functions the same as *as though* -- it is an adverb clause modifying *felt*. Ask yourself, "How did he feel?" "Like he was..." That shows it's an adverb clause.

Comment: So what's the function of the comma? Would the sentences be ungrammatical without it?

Comment: The function of the comma is to introduce the dependent adverb clause (first example), or to introduce a long clause of additional information (second example).